# remote form_tag in rails3 without a named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

what is the proper incantation to make this actually post asynchronously?

```
form_tag :controller => :magic, :action => :search, :method => post, :remote => true do
```

method=post and remote=true just get squashed on the end of the url instead of actually making it an ajax post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only way I found to do it is to wrap the url parameters in the url_for method.

```
form_tag url_for(:action => :create, :id => @artist.id), :remote => true do
```

However, if you need to the pass the `method` parameter you might need to wrap that and the remote in parentheses.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what you need:

```
form_tag( { :controller => :magic, :action => :search, :method => post }, { :remote => true } ) do ....
```

Its sort of a bad design, but the Rails `form_tag` methods require TWO hashes - the url_for options hash, and the regular options hash. This has generated much confusion for many Rails programmers. If you don't add the delineating hash boundaries, all of the options get passed to url_for(), ruining the `:remote => true`.

This will add `data-remote="true"` to your form (to be used with unobtrusive javascript, as others have mentioned). From there you need to create the appropriate AJAX to binding to do the request.

Though really you should be using a named route like `magic_search_path` instead of the controller/action parameters.

Comment: FYI, you can see the two hash options in the form_tag method prototype: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M006397 .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `form_remote_tag` instead:

```
form_remote_tag(:url => { :controller => :magic, :action => :search }) do
```

The default http method is post.

If you do want to pass extra parameters on a `form_tag` you need to make them into a separate hash from the url parameters, like this:

```
form_tag { :controller => :magic, :action => :search }, { :method => post, :remote => true } do
```

Comment: The correct answer is to separate the two hash parameters, but in Rails 3 works with `form_tag` and the `:remote => true` parameter. Rails 3 aims to be unobtrusive with the javascript generated, and the logic for sending it as ajax request lies now in the client side, with the Javascript driver of your choice. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript