# form_tag url_for with :method "delete", id and :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

I have the following `form_tag` working:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => "profiles", :action => "remove_academic", :method => :delete), :id => "remove_major_goal", :remote => true do %>
```

However, the HTML produced shows that :method => "delete" isn't working. So I found a few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507551/remote-form-tag-in-rails3-without-a-named-route) here on `form_tag` and tried this:

```
<%= form_tag url_for({ :controller => "profiles", :action => "remove_academic", :method => "delete" }, { :id => "remove_major_goal", :remote => true }) do %>
```

However that kicks back an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

DELETE is not a valid value of the method attribute for a HTML form element. You would probably be better inserting a `<input type="hidden" name="method" value="delete" />` inside the form (or use a helper method to do so).

Update:

Try one of these:

```
form_for url_for(:controller => "", :action => ""), :method => "delete", …

form_for { :controller => "", :action => "" }, { :method => "delete", … }
```

The second set of braces in the second form maybe unnecessary. Likewise, they might be needed in the first form.

Comment: The docs mention `"delete"`: The method to use when submitting the form, usually either “get” or “post”. If “put”, “delete”, or another verb is used, a hidden input with name _method is added to simulate the verb over post. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: Yes you are right about the method option. Editing original answer to include corrected version of the method calls.