# Converting Form_remote_tag to form_tag for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read lot of tutorials and information about form_remote_tag and form_tag but still unable to successfully replace form_remote_tag with form_tag (nothing show up, error 500). I don't really understand what I did wrong, I'm fairly new to Rails btw.

```
<%= form_remote_tag(:url => {:action => 'group_by', :id => @account.id},
                    :before => 'modalSpinner().open()',
                    :complete => 'Control.Modal.close()',
                    :html => {:id => 'group_by_form', :method => :post}) do %>
```

this is my attemp:

```
<%= form_tag (:url => {:action => 'group_by', :id => @account.id, :remote => true},
                    :id => 'group_by_form') do %>
```

Comment: If you get an error it certainly has some text in it?

Comment: because this is the view so I test it directly on the website, it just said "there was an internal error (500) servicing your request"

Comment: Try this: `<%= form_tag ({:action => 'group_by', :id => @account.id}, {:remote => true, :id => 'group_by_form'}) do %>`

Comment: it was answered earlier - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507551/remote-form-tag-in-rails3-without-a-named-route

Comment: not really, i follow that answer and what i get is <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/recommendations/group_by/10299" data-remote="true" method="post"> still no ajax call

Comment: moment, if there's 500 in browser there MUST be an error message in log file.

Comment: hi Michael, i fix that error, so now everything is showing, but there is no Ajax call. the form_remote_tag generates "new AjaxRequest", "asynchronous:True, evalScripts:true, parameters:Forms.serialize(this), but the form_tag generates none of those